# Convert string to number using i18n in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

Using the `ng.IFilterService` in `AngularJs` I can convert a number to a string. The [numberFilter](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1ab4e44443716c33cd857dcb1098d20580dbb0cc/src/ng/filter/filters.js) uses i18n to determine if it needs a period or a comma to format the number.

Like so:

```
var numberString = $filter('number')(1.1234, 2);
// numberString = 1,12 when using i18n for nl-nl (Netherlands)
```

What I am looking for, and so far haven't found, is how to do this in reverse.

When having a string value `'1,12'` and knowing the i18n setting for decimal separator (in this case a comma) one would know enough to convert it back. Although I can't find any method in `AngularJS` to do this.